# Map Reduce Mapper and Reducer Intra Parallelism

Tags: multithreading, mapreduce

For sake of clarity these questions are posed, given that hardware has many resources to that we want to utitilze to increase throughput, and also based on the discussions I see on these topics in various forums:

1. If I have, say 10 Mappers that are running, does this mean a single thread only, or N threads able to work on that given Split? I am not sure from the texts, but I would assume that would be possible and the case.
2. For a Reducer, I read it works on the Keys in parallel. I assume this means intra Reducer and hence again that N threads could be processing N Keys in parallel.
3. Could those N threads in the Reducer be further sub-divided? E.g. finding the maximum in a long list of Values for few Keys is doable, e.g. finding the max for the Key. Or is this not so?
4. If my assumptions on Reducers are correct, then this would imply that little used Reducers and skewness are less of an issue, or that incorrectly designed Custom Partitioners are not so bad. But the fact that such discussions are raised means that I need to check these assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following points may be helpful.

Firstly the number of mappers in any program is equal to the number of splits of your data and each mapper works on one split assigned to it. The mapper is tried to be invoked in the same node where the split is available. This is called locality of data.

The number of reducers for any job are equal to the number of partitioners for that job. The output of each mapper is hashed into the partition and each key and list of values from each partition bucket are sent to the reducer assigned to that partition.

On each node maybe the Mapreduce framework implements threading at its level which may use accelerated gpu or cpu for threading. That may be possible. But the parallelism that is operated on the big picture is the mappers and reducers operating on different nodes in parallel.

Hadoop allows the user to specify a combiner function to be run on the map output, and the combiner function’s output forms the input to the reduce function. Because the combiner function is an optimization, Hadoop does not provide a guarantee of how many times it will call it for a particular map output record, if at all. In other words, calling the combiner function zero, one, or many times should produce the same output from the reducer. Combiner functions are usually a reduce function.

Example if combiner is used on mapper's output
If first mapper output's be like

(1950, 0)

(1950, 10)

(1950, 20)

and second mapper output's

(1950, 23)

(1950, 30)

The reduce function will then be called with

(1950, [20,30])

Comment: 1st paragraph was understood.

Comment: I understand that the second paragraph is not true. You can have less reducers than partitioners, it will juts run more slowly. Slots, what if all busy?

Comment: Third paragraph: maybe, maybe. There are multi-threading Mappers, but I think the point you make is as I see it.

Comment: 4th point well understood, except can the processing of the reduce work in parallel or does it process k1 first, then k2 and so on ?